# SQL Server 2012 Create index with Sort In TempDb On - Gains False?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I create an index e.g

```
Create nonclustered index(Path, Value, Id) with(sort_in_tempdb=on);
```

It doesn't fail but when looking at the index in SMMS, it says `False`. Any ideas why?

EDIT: Can not find any schema to query for the value of this setting. Tried `sys.Indexes` but with no luck.

//Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 'Sort in tempdb' valid only while creating an index. And after index has been created it (an option, not index) becomes senseless. Any other operations like inserts, updates and deletes does not apply sorting in tempdb, or even apply, but this has no any relevance to this option value used while creating index

Comment: How about when it updates the statistics?

Comment: And just to get confirmed I understood: creating an index like that on an empty table is pointless?

Comment: Yes - about empty table

Comment: What do you mean about statistics?

Comment: When Sql Server thinks they are fragmented and will update the index statistics, will it have any effect then?

Comment: No - statistics objects is VERY small and thus - no needs to use tempdb - related to size of index - updating statistics is mainly the Read operation - no needs an additional sorting, since index already exists

Comment: @Daniel - Updating the statistics has precisely nothing to do with fragmentation. Stats get updated after a certain threshold of modifications are made to a table.

Comment: So the level of fragmentation is not a result of inserts and updates and an indication on when a index needs to be rebuilt?

Comment: @Daniel: the level of logical (not physical of the MDF) fragmentation is a measure on all insers, updates and deletes because of page splits, row overflow, forward pointers, deletes etc. It can be used to identify when to rebuild: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: @Daniel - Fragmentation and statistics updates are completely orthogonal is the point I was trying to make. An index could have zero fragmentation but still be due a statistics update.